# Call a webmethod in a webmethod

Tags: java

I would like to know how can I call other webmethod when I already in a webmethod?
FOR EXAMPLE,
webmethodA and webmethodB.
when I am in webmethodA and I wanted to call webmethodB.
I really dont know how.

Comment: why can't you just call it like any other method?

Comment: hi @ScaryWombat I wonder how as the webmethod name is different from Java. it looks something like this WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public List<Request> hello(@WebParam(name = "username") String name)

Comment: try just calling it as `hello ("Hoe Luen");`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i guess it works. havent try it yet but at least no error occur. pls write it as answer so i can can up for u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just call it like any other method, so try

just calling it as `hello ("Hoe Luen");`